# WxPython : Button Events

Tags: python, button, wxpython

Is there a way, that I could bind two events to a button in a sequential way. What I mean is as following:

In this example buttons 1 & 2 are bonded to their events respectively.

```
self.button1 = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'BUTTON1')
self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton1)

self.button2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Button2')
self.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton2)


def OnButton1(self,event):
    a = 1
    b = 3
    print a+b # basically some commands
    # Here I want to execute OnButton2 EVENT - So I use the following LINE
    OnButton2(event)
    # But the above command should not be executed unless the OnButton2 event has processed in the past - (Meaning unless the Button2 event has happen in the past) So How would I solve that problem.
    # It should be like IF CONDITION (BUTTON 2 HAS BEEN PRESSED IN THE PAST) - EXECUTE: SOME BASIC COMMANDS LIKE PRINT "HELLO"

def OnButton2(self,event):
    c = 4
    d = 5
    print c*d
```

Comment: `self.OnButton2(event)`?

Comment: You can always put code in function and use it in two binded functions

Comment: what do you mean "the traditional way of binding did not work." ?

Comment: What do you mean by "want to execute OnButton2 EVENT"? Are you trying to fire that event from within `OnButton1`?

Comment: @SelçukCihan Exactly.

Comment: EDITED THE QUESTION - PLEASE READ COMMENTS